# Why this code doesn't work, how do I grab a specific part of url?

Tags: python, django

I have the following url `http://localhost:8000/enthusiastically-synergize-optimal-results-after-proactive-total-linkage/edit/` and would like to access that slug from this url in this function so I can use it. In class based view I could use `self.kwargs.get('smthng')` and grab that but don't know how do I do that here:

```
def permission_of_user_for_posts(request):
post = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug= request.GET.get('blog_slug'))
if request.user.username == post.author:
    return True
return False


@user_passes_test(permission_of_user_for_posts)
def blog_update(request, blog_slug):
blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=blog)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.author = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

form = BlogForm(instance=blog)
context= {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'blogs/form.html', context)
```

or is there something else that I am doing it wrong in `permission_of_user_for_posts` function? please help me thank you

edit: this is url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', blogs_view.home, name='home'),
    path('blogs/', blogs_view.blogs, name='blogs'),
    path('<slug:blog_slug>', blogs_view.blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    path('post/', blogs_view.blog_create, name='blog_create'),
    path('<slug:blog_slug>/edit/', blogs_view.blog_update, name='blog_update'),
    path('<slug:blog_slug>/delete/', blogs_view.blog_delete, name='blog_delete'),
]
```

Comment: show your urls.py.

Comment: I just added urls.py and also I did a mistake, the function is `blog_update`. question updated

Comment: This code doesn't actually make any sense at all. The only argument to `permission_of_user_for_posts` is the user, not the request. And the slug is a parameter to `blog_update`, it is not in request.GET.

Comment: I am new in Django, I was looking for a solution as most of functions take `request` as argument I passed `request` as argument too but I didn't know the only argument is `user`. How would you write your own function to make this work? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is not to use the decorator or a separate function at all. Just check the post in the view:

```
def blog_update(request, blog_slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
    if not request.user == blog.author:
        raise PermissionDenied 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this's a nice solution